# Allow XMLHttpRequest Execution From Local File

Tags: javascript, security, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a JavaScript client application that uses the XMLHttpRequest object to fetch XML data from a server. However, all browsers except IE7/8 deny the request due to security concerns as outlined in the Same Origin Policy. It's important that this application works in IE, FF, and Chrome when run as a local file.

I've found success in Chrome when I use the `--disable-web-security` flag, but I can't imagine clients laughing it off when I say "Oh, make sure you disable web security or else it won't work."

I'd really appreciate some help!

EDIT: I don't have access to the server the XML comes from.

Comment: It's not something you can do without asking user to disable web security. Web apps are not good for local files.

Comment: @Mohsen Is there some way I can request permission from the browser (and in turn the user) to run?

Answer (score 1):

You may build a kind of proxy, a serverside application somewhere on the web, which retrieves the XML and delivers the xml inside a javascript-file.

Comment: @Dr.Molle That's disappointing, but thanks for your help. Does anyone know how to bypass the security in FF like I did with Chrome in the OP?

Comment: Look at this: http://dirolf.com/2007/06/enabling-cross-domain-ajax-in-firefox.html , maybe it still works.